# Error undefined reference to `cutCreateTimer'

Tags: cuda, makefile

I have the cuda 4.0 toolkit installed in my Ubuntu 12.04 server. When I am trying to build a cuda code present in Rodinia benchmark suite. I was  getting the following error. i.e, after running the make command

```
ncclab@slave13:~/Downloads/rodinia_2.4$ make
cd cuda/cfd;            make;   cp euler3d euler3d_double pre_euler3d pre_euler3d_double /home/ncclab/Downloads/rodinia_2.4/bin/linux/cuda  
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ncclab/Downloads/rodinia_2.4/cuda/cfd'
nvcc  -O2 -Xptxas -v --gpu-architecture=compute_20 --gpu-code=compute_20 euler3d.cu -o euler3d -I/if10/kw5na/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK4/C/common/inc  -L/if10/kw5na/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK4/C/lib 
euler3d.cu:35: warning: #warning "the kernels may fail too launch on some systems if the block length is too large"
euler3d.cu:35: warning: #warning "the kernels may fail too launch on some systems if the block length is too large"
```

By here the euler3d was built

```
nvcc -Xptxas -v -O3 --gpu-architecture=compute_20 --gpu-code=compute_20 euler3d_double.cu -o euler3d_double -I/if10/kw5na/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK4/C/common/inc  -L/if10/kw5na/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK4/C/lib 
/tmp/tmpxft_0000532d_00000000-12_euler3d_double.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_0000532d_00000000-1_euler3d_double.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x22d9): undefined reference to `cutCreateTimer'
tmpxft_0000532d_00000000-1_euler3d_double.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x22f7): undefined reference to `cutStartTimer'
tmpxft_0000532d_00000000-1_euler3d_double.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2457): undefined reference to `cutStopTimer'
tmpxft_0000532d_00000000-1_euler3d_double.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x246c): undefined reference to `cutGetAverageTimerValue'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [euler3d_double] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ncclab/Downloads/rodinia_2.4/cuda/cfd'
cp: cannot stat `euler3d_double': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `pre_euler3d': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `pre_euler3d_double': No such file or directory
make: *** [CUDA] Error 1
```

By searching I came to  know that there may be a problem with libcutil
But I had the libcutil_x86_64.a in ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib

Edit: The contents of various folders are
ncclab@slave13:~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib$ ls

```
libcutil_x86_64.a  libparamgl_x86_64.a  librendercheckgl_x86_64.a
```

~/Downloads/rodinia_2.4/cuda/cfd$ ls

```
euler3d     euler3d_double.cu  Makefile~        pre_euler3d.cu         README
euler3d.cu  Makefile           Makefile_nvidia  pre_euler3d_double.cu  run
```

ncclab@slave13:~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc$ ls

```
bank_checker.h              cutil_inline.h          GL                nvVector.h           stopwatch_base.h
cmd_arg_reader.h            cutil_inline_runtime.h  multithreading.h  nvWidgets.h          stopwatch_base.inl
cuda_drvapi_dynlink.c       cutil_math.h            nvGlutWidgets.h   paramgl.h            stopwatch.h
cutil_gl_error.h            dynlink                 nvGLWidgets.h     param.h              stopwatch_linux.h
cutil_gl_inline.h           dynlink_d3d10.h         nvMath.h          rendercheck_d3d10.h
cutil.h                     dynlink_d3d11.h         nvMatrix.h        rendercheck_d3d11.h
cutil_inline_bankchecker.h  error_checker.h         nvQuaternion.h    rendercheck_d3d9.h
cutil_inline_drvapi.h       exception.h             nvShaderUtils.h   rendercheck_gl.h
```

the partial contents of the makefile are

```
all: euler3d euler3d_double pre_euler3d pre_euler3d_double

euler3d: euler3d.cu
    nvcc  -O2 -Xptxas -v --gpu-architecture=compute_20 --gpu-code=compute_20 euler3d.cu -o euler3d -I$(CUDA_SDK_PATH)/common/inc  -L$(CUDA_SDK_PATH)/lib $(CUTIL_LIB)

euler3d_double: euler3d_double.cu
    nvcc -Xptxas -v -O3 --gpu-architecture=compute_20 --gpu-code=compute_20 euler3d_double.cu -o euler3d_double -I$(CUDA_SDK_PATH)/common/inc  -L$(CUDA_SDK_PATH)/lib $(CUTIL_LIB)


pre_euler3d: pre_euler3d.cu
    nvcc -Xptxas -v -O3 --gpu-architecture=compute_20 --gpu-code=compute_20 pre_euler3d.cu -o pre_euler3d -I$(CUDA_SDK_PATH)/common/inc  -L$(CUDA_SDK_PATH)/lib $(CUTIL_LIB)

pre_euler3d_double: pre_euler3d_double.cu
    nvcc -Xptxas -v -O3 --gpu-architecture=compute_20 --gpu-code=compute_20 pre_euler3d_double.cu -o pre_euler3d_double -I$(CUDA_SDK_PATH)/common/inc  -L$(CUDA_SDK_PATH)/lib $(CUTIL_LIB)
```

The euler3d has been successfully built. The errors are occurring for all the remaining three files.So I don't think there is any problems in the directories they are referring to

I really don't understand why the undefined reference to `cutCreateTimer' and others are occurring. But searching in SE I came to know that when there is any problem with cutil.h or libcutil these problems exits. I was a newbie of linux environment. So please help me

Edit 2: In a include file named make.config the following lines were present

```
# CUDA SDK installation path
#SDK_DIR = $(HOME)/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C
SDK_DIR =/if10/kw5na/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK4/C
#SDK_DIR =/if10/kw5na/NVIDIA_CUDA_Computing_SDK4/C
```

Here by default the 2nd option was selected and the euler3d was built. So I thought there may be a problem because of this. But changing it does not change the problem I was facing

and about cutil library present in make file

```
CUDA_SDK_PATH := $(SDK_DIR)

# Determine the correct version of the cutil library
CUTIL_LIB = # -lcutil
ifeq ($(shell uname -m), x86_64)
    ifeq ($(shell if test -e $(SDK_DIR)/lib/libcutil_x86_64.a; then echo T; else echo F; fi), T)
        CUTIL_LIB = #-lcutil_x86_64
     endif
endif
```

Which I think was correct

Comment: I downvoted this question. You need to explain all the paths that are appearing in above and show us your understanding and what exactly you are trying to do ?

Comment: @SagarMasuti Sorry, I don't know much about the issue. So I did not write what I am understanding......

Comment: so change the variable in `Makefile` which are pointing to the `include` path and `lib` path to point to your cuda sdk where you have shown us the `inc` and `lib` i.e., `-I/if10/kw5na/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK4/C/common/inc` to `~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc` and same with `lib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your compile command is specifying the library path, but not the library itself that is providing the `cut...` functionality.

This is apparently the makefile line that is generating the `nvcc` compile command for `euler3d_double`:

```
euler3d_double: euler3d_double.cu
    nvcc -Xptxas -v -O3 --gpu-architecture=compute_20 --gpu-code=compute_20 euler3d_double.cu -o euler3d_double -I$(CUDA_SDK_PATH)/common/inc  -L$(CUDA_SDK_PATH)/lib $(CUTIL_LIB)
```

This is the generated compile command:

```
nvcc -Xptxas -v -O3 --gpu-architecture=compute_20 --gpu-code=compute_20 euler3d_double.cu -o euler3d_double -I/if10/kw5na/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK4/C/common/inc  -L/if10/kw5na/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK4/C/lib
```

You'll note that the last two tokens in the makefile line are:

```
-L$(CUDA_SDK_PATH)/lib $(CUTIL_LIB)
```

The `-L$...` token is getting converted to the correct library path.  But the `$(CUTIL_LIB)` token should be getting converted to something like `-lcutil` or perhaps `-lcutil_x86_64`, but that is not happening.  As a result, the library that provides the `cut...Timer...` functions is missing, and so those appear to be undefined.

I would inspect the `Makefile` carefully to see if there are any end-of-line characters or other oddities that are different between the line that specifies how `euler3d_double` should be built and the previous lines that specify how `euler3d` should be built.

You should also be able to confirm this by looking at the `nvcc` compile command line generated for `euler3d` (which you don't show) and comparing it to the one for `euler3d_double` (which is failing).

Comment: Your `CUTIL_LIB` assignment is wrong.  Why are the `-lcutil` and the `-lcutil_x86_64` tokens commented out?